# Appropriate Honorifics for Fan Letter

Tags: culture, honorifics

I wrote a fan letter to Japanese actors that I admire.

It was compulsory to write his name on the envelope,

so I just simply put **Xさん**

However, I later noticed that everyone seems to address him as **X様**

I was quite confused since I have never seen anyone address him this way on SNS

(i.e. usually it was his nickname or Xくん　or Xちゃん）

Is this a common practice in Japanese or something?

[image]

Original Photo

- https://pbs.twimg.com/media/DNJfOB1UMAAoQa9.jpg
- https://pbs.twimg.com/media/DNOYXdrV4AAyoHY.jpg

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We are discussing two separate things here.

**On the envelope**:

It is just customary to use 「～～～～様」 on the envelope.  How you address your star in your imagination or what you call him/her when talking to someone about him/her is ***irrelevant*** here.

The only mail I have ever received with "[my name] + 君{くん}" was the New Year cards from my teachers in my elementary school days.  Teachers used 「君」 for boys and 「さん」 for girls.  「様」 would have been unnatural in that relationship and age difference.

In the case of fan letters, 「様」 would be the only proper honorific choice even if your star were 30 years younger than you.

**In the actual letter**:

This is altogether another matter from the above.  On the letter pad, you can address your star using whatever honorific you usually call him with -- さん、くん、ちゃん, etc.  You can also just use his/her nickname without an honorific as well.

This is all about Public vs. Private (envelope vs. letter pad).  We need to make a distinction.

Answer (score 0):

When you write to someone it’s a minimum manner to put ‘様’ just below the addressee’s name on the envelopes.

When you have chance to write to some entities contrary to a person, you should put ‘御中’ (onchu).

Like below

マル 様

スタックエクスチェンジ  御中